# Transfinite Induction Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $B_b\subset B_a$ and $B_b$ has cardinality less than $c$ for all ordinals $b < a$, does it follow that  $\bigcup_{b<a} B_b$ has cardinality less than $c$?

Would it simply "go without saying" that this union has cardinality less than $c$ because, otherwise, there must exist $b$ less than $a$ with $B_b$ not having cardinality less than $c$?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial. In the interest of everyone involved, you should use that to improve the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 2):

No, this doesn't follow. Fix a strict well-order $\prec$ of $\mathbb R$. Let $( x_{\alpha} \mid \alpha < \mathfrak{c})$ be the strictly $\prec$-increasing enumeration of $\mathbb R$. For $\alpha < \mathfrak{c}$ let
$$
B_{\alpha} := \{ x_{\beta} \mid \beta < \alpha \}.
$$

Each $B_{\alpha}$ has cardinality $\operatorname{card}(\alpha) \le \alpha < \mathfrak{c}$ and for $\alpha < \beta < \mathfrak{c}$ we have $B_{\alpha} \subseteq B_{\beta}$. But
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha < \mathfrak{c}} B_{\alpha} = \mathbb{R}
$$
has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: @bof Because of the poor formatting of the question I wasn't sure whether $c$ was just some generic cardinal or $c$ was supposed to be $\mathfrak{c}$ - the continuum. That's why I decided to cover both cases in one answer.